# AMPSCRIPT lookup rows - how to limit results to most recent

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Very new to lookuprows. No idea what I'm doing. I have a form that's set to append. And then I have an email with lookuprows that's scheduled to send me results daily. However, I want to limit results to within 24 hours. Currently I'm getting every result, ever. When I added the below code, I get nothing. When I take out  `if @InforowCount > DateAdd(@Date1, -1, "d")` and replace it with the standard  if @InforowCount > 0, then I get the complete list of results again.

```
    %%[
   var @ALL_DE_rows, @Inforow, @InforowCount, @i, @Date1
  set @Info_DE_rows = LookupRows(@EVENT_DE,"Registered_On",@Registered_On)

  set @InforowCount = rowcount(@Info_DE_rows)
set @Date1= FormatDate(Now(1), "s")

  if @InforowCount > DateAdd(@Date1, -1, "d")


  then

    /*This sets the row number, auto incrementing on each loop till it reaches the last row*/
    for @i = 1 to @inforowcount do
```

Comment: you should review look at lookuporderrows

Comment: thanks! @EazyE that was the solution.